# Issue with importing entire file such as parameters.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, import

I am recently having to deal with the following issue:

*TS2339: Property 'activityTime' does not exist on type 'typeof import...'*

In our project we commonly import our parameters.js as the following:

*import * as params from 'parameters'*

But parameters.js are kept locally and does not always contain optional configs. So the following code just gets flagged:

```
if (params.activityTime) {
// do something
}
```

We have quite a few of these throughout the project and adding @ts-ignore everywhere just gets messy.

I had thought about doing something like **const p: any = params;** in every place where params are imported, but that creates additional const in most of the files so I ended up discard that approach.

Without altering our parameters.js, is there a way to cast **params** as **any**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare the variable, so that TypeScript knows its type:

```
import * as params from './parameters';

declare const params: {
  activityTime?: number;
};
```

Comment: Thank you @rveerd!